# jquery popup image

Tags: jquery, popup

I am looking for jquery script of popping up an image onmouseover..
i did this using javascript but it is not browser supportive.. so looking for jquery script..
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$("#hoverable_container").hover(
    function(){
        $("#imageid").show();
    },
    function(){
        $("#imageid").hide();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's hover method works well for this, but that's already been answered. I'd recommend using the [HoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) instead, though, as this won't cause issues such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638433/jquery-hover-used-for-submenus-causing-bouncing). The only diference between the two is the overhead to load the HoverIntent plugin and calling the method as:

```
$("#hoverable_container").hoverIntent(
    // functions here
);
```